# change window.parent.name for cross domain sites

Tags: html, asp.net, cross-domain

I am able to change the parent window name using

```
window.parent.name
```

But when my app is hosted inside an iframe in different site (cross domain) i am not able to do the same !!

I need to change the parent window name to navigate like the one below

```
<a id="game" href="website.aspx" target="Application2">Click for application 2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the window name of another domain

Instead use the target `_top` or `_parent` in your link

Comment: I have two applications hosted in two different domains, so on click of a button in one app i will navigate to tab of browser containing another app and vice versa!!

Comment: That will not be possible. You can only access windows you opened yourself to the same domain your opened it from

Comment: oh :( if the app is accessed directly i am able to navigate among different tabs by setting the window.name, but since its inside iframe i am not able to set the name!!
is there any other way to navigate to different tab where the app is already opened?!

Comment: If you set the name of your own window (the window that hosts the app, e.g. the iframe) you may be able to change to the tab with a focus

Comment: it creates one more iframe when i navigate!! iframe inside iframe